# SQL Server fulltext - Search failures

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

After four years of working without error our full text searches have been returning results that are incorrect.  Sometimes we get fewer matches than expected, sometimes more.  Back to back searches for the exact same search criteria can give different results.  **This problem comes and go's at random times.**  Mostly it works correctly.

The full text table contains 30,038 entries and is rarely updated, two records per week would be a lot.

MSSQL version 11.0.7493.4.

You can try the search by visiting https://revisor.mo.gov/main/Home.aspx

Any insights appreciated.

edit:  The query to search for mule. which should return 14 matches.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON; SELECT [BID] FROM [StatConst].[revision].[SectFullText] WHERE  CONTAINS(body, '"mule" ') and [hist] Is Null
```

[StatConst].[revision].[SectFullText] has four columns,

```
BID int
Body nvarchar(MAX)
hashnum int
hist int
```

Comment: Not sure how providing a link to a webpage demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @SeanLange - shows how the searches are generated.  The issue can't be demonstrated unless it is in the failure mode.  What I use to determine if the search is failing is a search for mule.  Should return 14 matches.

Comment: No this is showing a front end that is apparently displaying the results. Maybe you have nolock on your queries, maybe there are other things in your query that might be problematic. Without any details other than "it isn't working" nobody can help.

Comment: Where is the query? We also need to see the schema definition

Comment: @SeanLange - see edits to OP

Comment: @Charlieface - see edits to OP

Comment: [dup on MS q&a](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/636399/sql-server-fulltext-search-failures.html)

Comment: @SMor - yes that is me.

Comment: Can we also see the definition for the full-text catalog and index? Have you tried rebuilding the full-text catalog? `ALTER FULLTEXT CATALOG catalog_name REBUILD` Perhaps also check the log files for full-text: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/populate-full-text-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15#crawl